# Можно ли написать код на C++ для андроид?

Tags: android, java

1. Вот мне интересно: если написать код на C++ для андроид, он в процессе компиляции в обычный java превратиться, а после - в apk?
2. То есть через Dex2Jar спокойно можно открыть, или же на вид будет бинарник в HEX коде, как на винде?))
3. Просто интересно, как же можно самому защитить свой код, чтобы хотя бы ссылки не читали. Ведь я там и пароли, и ключи от playMarketa храню, а иначе никак. PlayMarket требует... Как быть-то?

Давайте немного порассуждаем. )

Comment: Где вы пароли и ключи от Google Play храните?

Comment: @Futurama, а вам что-нибудь говорит фраза "Android NDK"? Вы когда-нибудь работали с этим? Код на C++ компилируется в библиотеки .so. В java байт-код он, насколько я знаю, не превращается.

Comment: @katso, В файла java, который после в DEX открывается, плай маркет просит, говорит закинуть в переменную PUBLIC_KEY

Answer (score 3):

Ответ на вопрос в заголовке — [да, можно](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html). И код на C++ будет скомпилирован в нативный код для платформы (как уже сказали в комментариях — в `*.so`), в Java он превратиться никак не сможет.

Формально говоря, защитить код никак нельзя. Хотя бы потому, что все, что делает ОС при развертывании APK можно сделать вручную — у вас есть вся необходимая информация. Но можно серьезно усложнить реверс-инженеринг приложения. Более-менее стандартный путь — обфускация и оптимизация с помощью [ProGuard](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html).

Ключи для API, насколько я знаю, многие беспечно хранят как строковые константы, в более разумном случае делают обфускацию вручную (разбиение на несколько, простое кодирование в другой формат и так далее). Здесь нужно понимать, что ключ в принципе за конечное время все равно восстановить можно по той же причине — вы можете повторить действия ОС в рантайме, сэмулировать выполнение кода и отловить вызов API, провести атаку man-in-the-middle по сети и так далее.